# How to change 'text-decoration' property with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, text-decorations

I have table with following structure:

```
<table style=" margin-top: 10px; border: 1px wheat solid; width: 100%; font-size: 10px; font-family: Arial , Verdana;text-shadow:0px 1px 0px #000">
    <tr class="infoRow" style="background:#666666; ">
        <td>Element11 </td>
        <td style="font-size:12px; font-weight:bold; font-family: georgia;">Element12 </td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" class="check" /></td>
    </tr>  
    <tr class="infoRow" style="background:#666666; ">
        <td>Element21 </td>
        <td style="font-size:12px; font-weight:bold; font-family: georgia;">Element22 </td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" class="check" /></td>
    </tr>           
</table>
```

I want, after check `<input class="check" ... />` the value of the property text-decoration to make 'underline' on the following row.

```
$('.check').click(function(){
   $('infoRow').css("text-decoration", "underline");   
});
```

This code change all rows.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> ...to make 'underline' on the **following row**.

(My emphasis).

To underline it on the *following* row, you'd want to go up to the checkbox's parent row, then to its sibling row, then apply `css` to that:

```
$(this).closest('tr').next('tr').css('text-decoration', 'underline');
```

Separately, you probably want to test whether the checkbox is being checked or unchecked, e.g.:

```
$('.check').click(function(){
    $(this).closest('tr').next('tr').css(
        'text-decoration',
        this.checked ? 'underline' : 'none'
    );
});
```

[Live example](http://jsbin.com/ozomaz)

Comment: Nice answer.

My 2 cents - it is a better practice to add a `class` (and style it accordingly in the stylesheet) to the effected element instead of changing the style directly using the `.css()` method.