# jQuery CSS Font-Weight Normal Not Working

Tags: jquery, css

I've googled for the last two days and browsed this site, too, but found no similar problem. I am new to jQuery and hope this is no duplicate of other posts.

```
$(this).css("font-weight", "bold"); //this works
$(this).css({"font-weight":"bold"}); //this works as well

$(this).css("font-weight", "normal"); //this doesn't work
$(this).css({"font-weight":"normal"}); //this doesn't work either
```

Why is it that text font weight cannot be set to NORMAL (in my case)? I use Firefox 17.0.1, but the function to set the font to normal never works in an earlier version of Firefox as well.

**UPDATED**:
My problem was finally solved last night, after browsing this site and found quite a similar thing. A few folks had to search for `<b>` and `</b>` in an HTML snippet and I fixed my problem by

Using this:
"`$(this).find('strong, b').css('font-weight', 'normal')`"

Instead of:
"`$(this).css('font-weight', 'normal')`".

Problem solved! Thanks to everyone for lending me a hand yesterday.

Comment: have you checked in firebug.??? css may not apply to dom because `Normal` font means no css just use as default font.

Comment: it seems to work fine? http://jsfiddle.net/bXyd8/

Comment: It really doesn't work. But when I checked it out, the fold which "looks" bold is actually "not bold". The method I use is: fontWeight = $(this).css('font-weight');
   if (fontWeight == 'bold' || fontWeight == '700')
    {
    alert("bold");
    $(this).css("font-weight","normal");
    }

Comment: how about this $(this).css("font-weight", 400);

Comment: $(this).css("font-weight", 400); //this failed, too. But is the problem due to the font set bold by "<b>" and "</b>" in my PHP code?

Comment: I'll try Firebug. Just installed it a while ago.

Comment: @asepm, you should add clarifications and additional code into the question, instead of writing them in comments. As asked now, the question is really “not a real question”, since it says that something does not work when it demonstrably does – the issue is outside the code and explanations given in the question.

Comment: Yes, Jukka, well noted. Will take care of it in my future posts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My code based on your snippet:

```
<html>
    <head>
    <style type="text/css">
        td a:link {text-decoration: none; color: inherit; }
        td a:visited {text-decoration: none; color: inherit; }
        td a:active {text-decoration: none; color: inherit; }
        td a:hover {text-decoration: underline; color: blue; }
    </style>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        /*global $, jQuery, document*/
        $(document).ready(function () {
            "use strict";
            $('#text').click(function (event) {
                $(this).css("font-weight", "normal");
                event.preventDefault();
            });
        });
    </script>
    <title>View Data</title>
</head>
<body>
<p id="text" style="font-weight: bold;">Lorem ipsum</p>
</body>
</html>
```

[DEMO](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/46605743/normal%20test/index.html)

So I think that problem is with this line`'td[id="text_linked_to_detail_page"]'`, maybe try use dot notation. Or check if the ID is certainly unique.

Comment: Thanks for your kind efforts, factoradic. Have tried your code but still no success, unfortunately. I think, as per your assumption, it must have something to do with the Id, which I will have to change through php code. On a side note, I'm left wondering why "making it bold" is just a piece of cake.

Comment: well, the ID is right. when an alert function is provided instead of font-weight change, the alert showed up. so what's exactly the problem, anyone?

Comment: No problem. I don't know what is wrong. Your code snippet is correct. Maybe you should show whole js code. Firebug for Firefox has a special JavaScript console, it might be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

Normat is working fine could you cross check which version of the jquery you are using? give the command so that we also can understand your problem

script

```
$("#div1").css("font-weight", "bold");
$("#div2").css("font-weight", "normal");
$("#div3").css("font-weight", "bold");
$("#div4").css("font-weight", "");
```

HTML

```
<div id="div1" >some text</div>
<div id="div2" >some text</div>
<div id="div3" >some text</div>
<div id="div4" >some text</div>
<input type="button" onclick="javascript:$('#div1').css('font-weight','normal')" value="Normal"/>
<input type="button" onclick="javascript:$('#div1').css('font-weight','bold')" value="Bold"/>
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/C7nYG/2/)

Answer (score 1):

The normal is also working for me but if you have problem, try setting the font-weight to empty string, It would apply default which would be normal.

[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/TaHLA/1/)

```
$(this).css("font-weight", "");
```

Comment: agreed ......if you use empty string it will treat as a normal and will remove bold from fontweight

Comment: Just tried the above and visited the Live Demo page too. Even without a string, it didn't work at all.

Answer (score 1):

You might have problem with jQuery not css style.

My html:

```
<p id="text">Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet</p>
<p id="bold">Click to : bold</p>
<p id="normal">Click to : normal</p>
```

and jQuery:

```
function action() {
    "use strict";
    $("#normal").click(function () {
        $("#text").css("font-weight", "normal");
    });
    $("#bold").click(function () {
        $("#text").css("font-weight", "bold");
    });
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    "use strict";
    action();
});
```

Comment: The HTML part in one of my PHP files.
<head>
<style type="text/css">
td a:link {text-decoration: none; color: inherit}
td a:visited {text-decoration: none; color: inherit}
td a:active {text-decoration: none; color: inherit}
td a:hover {text-decoration: underline; color: blue}
</style>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function()
 {
 $('td[id="to_detail_page"]').click(function(e)
  {
   $(this).css("font-weight", "normal");
   e.preventDefault();
  });
 });
</script>
<title>View Data</title></head>
<body>
</body>

Answer (score 1):

This is the HTML part below PHP code in one of my PHP files.

```
<html>
    <head>
    <style type="text/css">
        td a:link {text-decoration: none; color: inherit;}
        td a:visited {text-decoration: none; color: inherit;}
        td a:active {text-decoration: none; color: inherit;}
        td a:hover {text-decoration: underline; color: blue;}
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function()
        {
            $('td[id="text_linked_to_detail_page"]').click(function(event)
            {
                $(this).css("font-weight", "normal");
                event.preventDefault();
            });
        });
    </script>
    <title>View Data</title>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: so what is wrong with this.? Also you forget `;` from css. I have updated above post

Comment: so tell me is there only single `DOM` with same id..?? Because each `DOM` must have unique ID.

Comment: frankly speaking, i'm a complete newbie in jQuery. i'm working on a personal project using Symbian, then PHP and now jQuery. Still trying to figure out what DOM really is, fella. BTW, I've tried this one "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8969689/how-to-change-text-decoration-property-with-jquery" but it doesn't work for me, either.

Comment: i'll let u know if i have more than one object/element with same id after reading this. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document_Object_Model

Comment: well DOM stands for DOCUMENT OBJECT MODEL. which means p a div h1 h2 all are DOM...

Comment: yes, buddy, i have more than one td with same id, which is all the rows in the table. how do i have to fix this, because this SINGLE id is used to determine that all td's in each tr are linked to the detailed page. but, guess what, the click event works just fine for each row (directing to their own UNIQUE details).

Comment: so you can add dynamic id as `text_linked_to_detail_page_1,text_linked_to_detail_page_2,text_linked_to_detail_page_3` and in jQuery get all the DOM as `$('td[id^="text_linked_to_detail_page_"]')`

Comment: well, that seems to be feasible to me (particularly the "$('td[id^="text_linked_to_detail_page_"]')" part). i'll give it a try and let you know the outcome later.

Answer (score 0):

Lets Make clear CSS `font-weight` Property

**Definition and Usage**

The `font-weight` property sets how `thick` or `thin` characters in text should be displayed.

#### Default value:normal

so **your code is working** because you setting default value to text but difference is you just not visually see the changes.

Comment: In fact, I populated a table through PHP and did all the formatting within the PHP code. I'm wondering if that might be the culprit. BTW, I am using a CSS snippet but I have no idea how to apply it to a table (there are two in the page) for all the td's in the 2nd table.

Comment: @asepm that is not because final result will be shown by browser.

Comment: @asepm so you need to ask appropriate question here...update your question or ask it again with all the code and necessary information..Thanx

Comment: Dipesh, thanks for tidying up my post. How come I don't see the change (bold to normal) visually, but I do see the change from normal to bold? Well, I can tell the difference between bold and not bold, LOL... This in fact is what I see in my PC and notebook.